# Does TideSDK work with Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, tidesdk

This question was asked here with no actual response.  Please don't stone me for asking it again.  However does CodeIgniter work with TideSDK? I have a Codeigniter build with file structure System folder - Application folder - index.php etc.  Works smoothly but i would like to try to build it into a Desktop app using TideSDK.  Does anyone know what i would need to configure to get it to work if it does indeed work with Codeigniter?

Answer (score 1):

This interested me, so I looked into it a bit further. After a bit if Googling, I found this, and got it to work.

https://github.com/ficeto/titanium-codeigniter

It's an install of codeigniter (v 1.7.2), working in titanium (TideSDK's previous name)